# Can background processes started from a loop in bash pick up values from a later iteration?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, while-loop

In Bash, if I have a `while true` loop where, at the top of the loop, I set a variable equal to the current `date`, and in consequent background commands I use this variable (e.g. to name an output file), what would happen if, say, the third execution of `date=$(date)` comes before the second execution of another command?

I.e.: given the following loop:

```bash
while : ; do
    date=$(date)
    backgroundcommand -o $date &
    backgroundcommand2 -o $date &
done
```

and if commands are executed in the following order:

```bash
    date=$(date) # first execution
    backgroundcommand -o $date & # first execution
    backgroundcommand2 -o $date & # first execution
    date=$(date) # second execution
    backgroundcommand -o $date & # second execution
    date=$(date) # third execution
    backgroundcommand2 -o $date & # second execution
    backgroundcommand -o $date & # third execution
    backgroundcommand2 -o $date & # third execution
```

does Bash keep track of variable states? E.g.: after 3 loops, will I have 3 pairs of files with the same date, or will I have two files, one file and three files with respectively the same name?

Comment: BTW, since your commands (other than the assignments to `date`) are being run in the background, chances are that the three `date` invocations will all happen in the same second, and thus have the same values in practice.

Comment: Similarly, your loop will very quickly overwhelm the process table and have ill effects on your system's usability, as it's starting background processes very, *very* quickly.

Comment: I'm trying to repeatedly (infinitely, hence the `while true`) use the `rec` command to record audio until a silence is detected, and consequently send this audio to a speech-to-text API. I don't want the `curl`s to block the while loop, though, because that'd mean I'm missing out on audio, so I was thinking of running those in the background. Yet that might make the `rec` output overwrite itself, unless I name the output file something unique, like the date.

Comment: So in your real-world use case, then you've got *something* that blocks. That's a lot more reasonable than being 100% purely background processes other than `date`.

Comment: ...btw, as an aside, you'd want `-o "$date"` instead of `-o $date` in practice -- that way the variable will always expand to precisely one argument, no matter whether that value contains characters in `$IFS` (which would otherwise be used to split it into multiple arguments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything in a subshell, or any backgrounded command, is a *completely separate process*; unlike a thread (which shares memory), such a separate process is utterly independent from the parent from which it was forked.

Consequently, the child cannot see updates to variable state which later take place in the parent, so its view of shell variables is strictly that of the variables **as they existed when the background process was created**.

Thus, the value of `$date` will always be that of the variable as of the time when the `backgroundcommand ... &` invocation took place, regardless of whether the parent process has updated the value since.

Answer (score 0):

The `backgroundcommandX -o $date &` will have the $date variable set at the value of the iteration.

You may have a problem with the `$date` variable that is the same because date as a granularity of 1 sec and if your loop takes less than a second to execute you end up with the same file name.

I would first use a a custom format to avoid spaces in the file name and maybe add miliseconds in the string:

```
date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S_%N"
```

Or you can add a pause in the loop:

```
sleep 2
```

so you are sure that there will not have 2 similar date string.